# Best approach to archive the Workflow log?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

We have a custom reusable workflow runs on the document library and logs the actions into a custom List. Now, we want to safely archive the workflow log. what would be the best approach? shall we do it using a Timerjob and move the data to a custom non-sharepoint database.

Comment: I think best is a pretty subjective word here. I personally don't see any issues with the plan that you have suggested in your question. What's motivating you to archive?

Comment: It is an approval workflow and business want to keep the track of approvals(who has approved & when)...

Comment: That makes sense. I'd added my thoughts on it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this project, I would probably use the same basic method that you have described here. But I'd likely use SSIS, rather than an SP timer job, to take the list items and transform them into a table structure into SQL Server. The main reason for putting them into a database is that it would make different types of analytics easier (reporting, data warehouse, etc). I suppose these are two equally valid approaches:

1. Perform the ETL as a timer job on the SharePoint server. If your in-house developers are more familiar with SharePoint development this will likely be the easiest solution. The main draw back of this is that you might be a little limited in the flexibility of how you process the data.
2. Perform the ETL as a [SQL Server Integration Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) package/job. If this project were being done at my current place of employment this is likely how we would handle it since the strongest common skill-set that our team shares is SQL Server. We would probably use the Managed Client Object Model to do the extract part of the ETL. I think this option is probably the most flexible as SSIS is really designed for this sort of work.

Really the details of which you choose should be what makes sense in your environment and with your skills and your teams skills. If you have a SharePoint server up and running, you probably also have a license for SSIS. So my best advice is that you pick the method that best fits your environment.